# How to populate a new html document with angular information retrieved from another html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a pretty basic page that contains a textarea that takes a bunch of text and parses it when a button is pressed. A modal then pops up so that the user can edit any information that was retrieved from parsing. Once Submit is pressed in that modal what I want to happen is for a new page to open displaying the information that was submitted, that information having come from the textarea and some textfields in the modal using angular.

So how can I go about creating a new html page and and populating it with the information that was accumulated though angular so that the user can see what was sent to the server?

Html:

```
<div class="content" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <textarea id="inputArea" rows="20" cols="100" data-ng-model="inputArea"></textarea>

    <div data-ng-include src="'views/confirm.html'"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Parsed Info</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="inline"><form><p> Property Infringed </p> <input type="text" data-ng-value="property" id="{{ property }}" ng-model="property"></form></div>
            <div class="inline"><form><p> Email of Sender </p> <input type="text" data-ng-value="email" id="{{ email }}" ng-model="email"></form></div>
            <div class="inline"><form><p> Name of Sender </p> <input type="text" data-ng-value="name" placeholder="e.g. John Smith" ng-model="name"></form></div>
            <div class="inline"><form><p> Date of Email </p> <input type="text" data-ng-value="date" placeholder="M/D/Y" ng-model="date"></form></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">App ID's</div>
            <div class="panel-body">        
                <table class="inline">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Android </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in andItems">
                        <td style="padding-right: 30px;">{{ item }} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="inline">
                    <tr>
                        <th>iOS</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in iosItems">
                        <td>{{ item }} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">Submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="btnDiv">

        <button id="detailsBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click='filter()'>Submit</button>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

$scope.andItems = [];
$scope.iosItems = [];
$scope.property = "";
$scope.email    = "";

$scope.filter = function() {

    var input = $scope.inputArea;

/* PROPERTY PARSER*/

    var property = "";
    for(var i = 0; i <= input.length; i++){
        if( input.substring(i, i+10) == "behalf of "){
            for(var j = i+10; j <= input.length; j++){
                if(input.substring(j, j+1) == " "){
                    break;
                }else{
                    property += input.substring(j, j+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.property = property;



/* ID PARSER      */

    //var ret = "Requested apps to be marked as unauthorized: ";
    var iosIds = [];
    var andIds = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= input.length; i++){
        if( input.substring(i, i+4 ) == "/id/"){
            var id = "";
            var isAndroid = false;
            for(var j = i+4; j <= input.length; j++){
                if(input.substring(j, j+1) == " " || input.substring(j, j+1) == "\n"){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    if(input.substring(j, j+1) == "."){
                        isAndroid = true;
                    }
                    id += input.substring(j, j+1);
                }
            }
            if(isAndroid){
                andIds.push(id);
            }else{
                iosIds.push(id);
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.andItems = andIds;
    $scope.iosItems = iosIds;

    $scope.open();

};

$scope.open = function () {

  console.log("test");

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modalContent.html',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
    windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
    resolve: {
      property: function () {
        return $scope.property;
      },
      email: function () {
        return $scope.email;
      },
      andItems: function () {
        return $scope.andItems;
      },
      iosItems: function () {
        return $scope.iosItems;
      }
    }
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
  }, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
};

});

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, property, email, iosItems, andItems) {

      $scope.property = property;
      $scope.email = email;

      $scope.andItems = andItems;
      $scope.iosItems = iosItems;


      $scope.ok = function () {

        $modalInstance.close();
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };
};
```

Comment: What have you done? Can you show your code?

Comment: Have you tried using localStorage yet?

Comment: @Backus I think I am having some headache already, thus I am finding it difficult to read some meaning into your code. But you can make it easier by creating a CodePen @ http://codepen.io. I suppose this is Ionic project